# How do I get SAS encoding option programmatically?

Tags: character-encoding, sas

How do I find out the SAS global `encoding` option programmatically? I can run `proc options`, and it will give me the answer, but I need to do it from code.

I am hoping for an answer on the lines of "look at the macro symbol &sysencoding", but this might be too much to hope for. I would prefer to avoid fragile things like writing to an external file and re-parsing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the GETOPTION function in Base SAS:

```
data _null_;
  val=GETOPTION('encoding');
  put val=;
run;
```

On my system this gives the log output

```
5    data _null_;
6      val=GETOPTION('encoding');
7      put val=;
8    run;

val=LATIN1
```

In SCL (SAS Component Language) you can use the OPTGETC and OPTGETN functions.
See the manual for your specific version of the SAS System for further details.

Answer (score 3):

In SAS 9.2 `&sysencoding` will give you the same thing as `getoption('encoding')` though the case differs (it's described briefly [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/whatsnew/62435/HTML/default/mcrolrefwhatsnew902.htm)).

```
157  %put &sysencoding;
wlatin1
158
159  data _null_;
160    val=GETOPTION('encoding');
161    put val=;
162  run;

val=WLATIN1
```